# Cup product mapping

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory

$
\newcommand{\OXD}{\mathcal{O}_X(D)}
\newcommand{\OXDD}{\mathcal{O}_X(D')}
$
Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over $k=\bar{k}$ an effective $D$ a divisor on $X$. Associated to $D$ we have a line bundle $\OXD$, and it turns out that we have
$$ D\sim D' \iff \OXD \cong  \OXDD, $$
where $\sim$ denotes linear equivalence of divisors. For every $D$ we have the cup-product map on the cohomology groups
$$ \mu: H^0(X,\OXD)\otimes H^0(X,K(-D))\to H^0(K) $$
which, if $\OXD = L$, can also be rewritten equivalently as
$$ \mu: H^0(X,L)\otimes H^0(X,K\otimes L^{-1})\to H^0(K). $$
Now we come to my question: I'm reading [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387909974) about curves and Brill-Noether theory and, at page $190$, they say that

> Given a non zero section $s \in H^0(L) $ such that $(s)=D$, the image
>   of  $$ s\otimes H^0(X,K\otimes L^{-1})\to H^0(K) $$ under $\mu $ is
>   equal to $H^0(X,K(-D))$.

**Could you help me understanding this claim?** 
I'm confused, especially because I was convinced that $H^0(X,K(-D))$ and $H^0(X,K\otimes L^{-1})$ were the same spaces... but from the above statement it looks like this is not the case.

Comment: Dear Abramo: I think the issue here is just a slight confusion between equality and isomorphism of sheaves. When you say that $H^0(X,K(-D))$ and $H^0(X,K \otimes L^{-1})$ are "the same" space, you are implicitly using an isomorphism between the sheaves $K \otimes L^{-1}$ and $K(-D)$. (Note that it doesn't really make sense to assert that these sheaves are "the same", since $K \otimes L^{-1}$ is not _a priori_ a subsheaf of $K$.) The statement you quote is just making explicit where that isomorphism comes from: namely, from multiplying by a nonzero section of $L$ which vanishes along $D$.

Comment: For completeness, let me say that one thing that might have made the quoted passage clearer is to point out that multiplication by $s$ gives an _injective_ map from $H^0(X,K \otimes L^{-1})$ to $H^0(K)$, hence an isomorphism onto its image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're definitely right!! So stupid of me

Comment: Dear Abramo, not stupid at all --- it's a tricky point!

Comment: I made my comments into an answer, to remove this question from the unanswered pile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dear Abramo: I think the issue here is just a slight confusion between equality and isomorphism of sheaves. When you say that $H^0(X,K(−D))$ and $H^0(X,K \otimes L^{−1})$ are "the same" space, you are implicitly using an isomorphism between the sheaves $K \otimes L^{−1}$ and $K(−D)$. (Note that it doesn't really make sense to assert that these sheaves are "the same", since $K \otimes L^{−1}$ is not a priori a subsheaf of $K$.) The statement you quote is just making explicit where that isomorphism comes from: namely, from multiplying by a nonzero section of $L$ which vanishes along $D$.

For completeness, let me say that one thing that might have made the quoted passage clearer is to point out that multiplication by s gives an *injective* map from $H^0(X,K \otimes L^{−1})$ to $H^0(X,K)$, hence an isomorphism onto its image.